# Does this database look OK? Did I normalize properly?

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I have the need to create a database for some data I have, and so I took a crack at it (as you would hope), and now I need help putting the finishing touches on it! Can you help me normalize this?

I took a picture of the design I created in Excel using **fake data**:

[image]

What you should know is that some games will be played 5v5 and some will be played 3v3. Instead of adding columns for Team1P1, Team1P2, Team1P3, etc., I wanted to leave it up to the experts to help me do this.

**Question:** Based on my file parser, my application will know whether a game has 6 players (3v3) or 10 (5v5). How can I structure the database to map those players back to the game? Instead of trying to put `Player` data into the `Games` table, should I add a column in `Players` which points to the `Game ID` ?

**Players**:
id | player_id | game_id | etc...

**Edit for clarification**

Picture Starcraft 2, or any other RTS game played online. When a game starts, it is a brand new slate. A set number of players join a match (3v3 or 5v5) and play against each other. At the end of the game, everyone has certain stat values (did they win or lose? How much gold did they have? How many kills, deaths, assists did they have?)

Each of these stats is specific to that player in that game.

If I play 2 games that day, I will look like this:

**id | player_id | stat1 | stat2 | stat3 |**
1  | 100 | 500 | 600 | 700
2  | 100 | 300 | 999 | 2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mostly agree with PeeHaa's answer, though I have a couple of changes.  First, I agree that the `id` fields in both the tables you propose, pr0tocol, are confusing since you also have `game_id` and `player_id` fields.  Just use those.

I also agree that you should have a separate `game_players` table that consists solely of `game_id` and `player_id` and both of those fields combined are the primary key of the table.

I feel your `stats` table should be keyed the same as the `game_players` table.  This way, not only are you keeping track of each individual player's stats, but you also have the ability to report statistics for individual games.

*Edit:*

Games:

```
  key
game_id  |  game_length  |  game_mode  |  game_type  |  ranked
```

Players:

```
   key
player_id  |  other player data - no stats in here
```

Game_Players

```
  key    |     key
game_id  |  player_id
```

Stats

```
  key    |     key
game_id  |  player_id  |  stat1  |  stat2  |  stat3  |  etc...
```

Using these four tables, you can keep track of all stats and be able to separate them based by player or game through whatever reports you choose to write.  It doesn't matter now how many games an individual player is assigned to, since it's only part of the key in the relevant tables.

Comment: The id field keeps the record unique. As can be seen in my update above, a player can play multiple games, meaning the player_id can be duplicated. If I get rid of the 'id' field, I no longer have a unique marker.  As for the stat table both of you have proposed, id | player_id | stattype | statvalue, doesn't work here.. If a player has played multiple games and has different stats for each game's conclusion, this structure is pointless. The stats should be attached to the player table, as they are the unique stat values for that player TO THAT GAME.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand that.  I'll update my answer to try to further illustrate what I'm saying as I don't think I've explained myself well enough.

Comment: Your comment makes more sense now. Let's chat about this for a second though. Since I am getting another company's data and not using my own (reading data from a log file parser), there is no other player data other than player_id and stats. Doesn't that theoretically make the Players table useless? Perhaps not, but I don't think I need a Player table if all it is holding is "player_id". What are your thoughts? What this basically makes me do is check if a player found in a log file has been in any game ever, and if so, don't add him to the player table (already exists). Its pointless for this

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, for a particular GAME that was played, the player's PLAYER_ID can be considered a "stat". In that case, just remove the stat table completely and put "all" of the player's stats (his ID and VALUES) inside of "Players" and everything is now super simplified for the better. No?

Comment: I'm totally wrong and you are right. The player's ID is the same in every game, the player's NAME is the same in every game. Just these two examples alone warrant the need for a player table that stores these COMMON values, and a stat mapping should be created for the stats that CHANGE!!!!

Comment: You lose the uniqueness of the player if you get rid of the `players` table.  In the logs you're getting, there isn't even a player name to tie to the record in the `players` table?  Your main question was "Did I normalize this properly?" and the answer was "no" based on the original information and the assumptions we had to make about how the data was being entered and used.  Hopefully this all helps point you in the right direction!

Comment: I actually added a comment before you typed yours, finally realizing where I went wrong. I hope you get the opportunity to read it and see :) Thanks for your help dude

Comment: Yup, I think you have it now.  Don't worry too much about not getting warnings - as long as you make the fields non-nullable it'll be hard to throw bad data in there.  And no problem, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I would make another table to map players and games.

I also notice you have stats in the player table.

It might be a better choice the create another table for the player stats. This way you don't need to change the table if you want to add some other stat in the future.

Table game_players:

```
game id // PK
player id // PK
```

Tables stats:

```
id
player id
type (e.g. stat1)
stat
```

Comment: So create a game_players table that has id | game_id (PK) | player_id, and when I write the data to the database in both the game and player columns, finish up by writing to the game_players table as well?  Also, I don't understand the stats table. Can you elaborate on its design and application? Why would it be a problem if I add a new stat to the Player field? Each stat is specific to a particular game, so a player's old stat will never change. Just in the future, the player table may have an additional column (with no values for previous players before the change)

Comment: The `game_players` table is just a mapping. The table has 2 `foreign keys` (gameid and playerid) and the `primary key` will be a combination of the gameid and the playerid.

Comment: @pr0tocol regarding: `Each stat is specific to a particular game`. Why do you have it in your player table than? Can you please expand your question to what the exact rules are?

Comment: I've edited my original post near the end for your review. I hope that makes it a bit more clear :) . You should notice that these are short 30-60 minute games, and the same person (player_id) can play multiple games and end up with different stats at the end of each individual game. I think my original Players table schema was appropriate, and your suggestion was just from your confusion. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

```
Game
----
GameId
Length
Mode
Type
Ranked
PRIMARY KEY (GameId)

Team
----
TeamId
TeamName (only if you need it)
... other stuff about team
PRIMARY KEY (TeamId)

Player
------
PlayerId
PlayerName
... other stuff about player
PRIMARY KEY (PlayerId)
```

And which player paricipates in which team:

```
TeamPlayer
----------
TeamId
PlayerId
PRIMARY KEY (TeamId, PlayerId)
FOREIGN KEY (TeamId)
  REFERENCES Team(TeamId)
FOREIGN KEY (PlayerId)
  REFERENCES Player(PlayerId)
```

and which teams in which game:

```
GameTeam
--------
GameId
TeamId
PRIMARY KEY (GameId, TeamId)
FOREIGN KEY (GameId)
  REFERENCES Game(GameId)
FOREIGN KEY (TeamId)
  REFERENCES Team(TeamId)
```

and statistics:

```
GamePlayerStatistics
--------
GameId
TeamId
PlayerId
... statistics columns per player per game
PRIMARY KEY (GameId, PlayerId)
FOREIGN KEY (GameId, TeamId)
  REFERENCES GameTeam(GameId, TeamId)
FOREIGN KEY (TeamId, PlayerId)
  REFERENCES TeamPlayer(TeamId, PlayerId)
```

If all your games have 2 teams exactly, the `GameTeam` table could be removed. You would then need two columns in `Game`, say `Team1Id` and `Team2Id` as Foreign Keys to `Team` and also some modifications to `Statistics` table.